# Bathroom exhaust fan heat loss

Tags: hvac

How much HEAT is lost in the winter by a bathroom exhaust fan running ALL of the time?  Conversely, in the summer time how much COOL air is lost by the fan running continuously?  It seems to me this would be like leaving a window or door open!

Comment: In the vast majority of cases where a vent fan is running "all the time" it's doing so by design, and reflects a total building approach that's much "tighter" than average, such that forced ventilation is required for occupant health and comfort. There's usually also a deliberate air intake built into such a system. Be sure you understand the actual house system before disabling the designed operation.

Comment: I am not sure where the close requesters are coming from. This is a good question even if it does not relate directly to some DIY home activity.

Comment: To answer this, you need to know how much air you're moving and how much you'll need to heat the air that replaces it. Air movement is a consequence of the fan's airflow (typically listed in CFM) and any restrictions imposed by its particular ductwork and damper. Once you know the air movement volume and how much hotter you'll be making the new air, you can then use the Heat Capacity (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity) of air to figure out how much energy you'll spend heating up the new air.

Comment: @Ecnerwal makes a good point but that might not be what we're dealing with.  A fan with a long run-on (mine were set to max -- over an hour -- when supplied) and a frequently-used bathroom could easily cause the fan to run much more than it should.  Or if a bathroom light is left on overnight (perhaps for a child) the fan will run constantly.  Even if it is intended to run flat out, that's based on certain assumptions about occupancy and use that may or may not be valid. BEra in mind that we don;t knwo where the OP is and therefore what's common construction there

Answer (score 4):

This isn't typically calculated, but here are a couple of gross estimates of the heat loss.

**Method 1:**

- Air requires in the ballpark of 0.24 BTU per pound to raise it 1 degree F.
- 1 CF of air weighs about 0.0807 lb, so it takes roughly 0.0194 BTU per cf per degree.
- A typical small bathroom fan exhausts about 70 CFM or 4,200 CF per hour.  That would take roughly 81.5 BTU per hour to change it 1 degree.
- The exhausted air will be replaced by outside air infiltrating through leakage.  Say you're in an area where the outdoor temperature is 40 degrees colder than indoor temperature in the winter.  That would require roughly 3,260 BTU per hour to make it the same temperature as the indoor air.
- If you're heating with electricity, 1 watt = 3.412 BTU/hr, so this example would be roughly equivalent to a load of 1 KW.  Running it continuously would  add about 700 KWH per month to your electric bill in the winter if that temperature difference was an average (roughly $100), not including the electricity to power the fan.

**Method 2:**

- There are online BTU calculators, like [this one](http://www.calculator.net/btu-calculator.html?).  They're used to estimate HVAC requirements, which is slightly different.  In the calculation above, I just looked at the heat (or cooling) required for the replacement air.  HVAC sizing considers maintaining a temperature difference inside insulated walls, HVAC duty cycling, and other factors.  But it's another crude estimation.
- For HVAC purposes, turning over room air 8 times per hour is a rough rule of thumb.  So 4,200 CF per hour would represent a 525 CF room.
- Using assumptions of "normal" insulation and the same 40 degree temperature difference, the calculator comes up with a 5,840 BTU/Hr HVAC unit.

These are very crude estimates, but you can play with the assumptions to get a ballpark idea of the heating and cooling load created by running the fan continuously.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question in a concrete fashion, we'd need to know how many cubic feet per minute (CFM) are actually being moved by the fan (usually less than it is "rated" at due to being rated with no duct attached, but used with a duct attached.)

Say it's 100 (it's probably not.) 60 minutes to the hour, so 6000 cubic feet per hour, or 6000/13.9  (so, 431.6) pounds of air per hour. Air has a specific heat of 0.24, so 103.5 BTU's per hour per degree Fahrenheit (working in "English" units mostly only used in the USA.)

So, if it's -20F out and 68F in, 9120 BTUs/hr

If it's 68F in and 98F out, 3110 BTUs/hr - also if it's 38F out, just heating, not cooling.

Any other temperature differential, do the math. Got a different airflow rate - do the other math further up the page, I've exposed the factors that most people don't learn (cubic feet per pound and specific heat) so you can figure out exactly how many BTUs/hr your ventilation requires. Incidentally, unless your house is very well insulated, 100CFM of ventilation is peanuts .vs. the radiative heat loss of your windows alone, much less the rest of the house.

As noted in my comment, this is almost always a designed operation, not a "builder mistake" - the operating cost is not all that great, particularly as contrasted with the costs of inadequate ventilation, such as a mold problem that requires gutting and disinfecting the house, or the cost of excessive passive ventilation (leaks, drafts) from sloppy construction.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it’s expensive to remove “conditioned” air and replace it with “unconditioned” air and then pay to “condition” it.

Exhaust fans are rated by CFM’s. That is, cubic feet per minute. So, if a fan is on 24/7, it won’t take long for the exhaust fan to exhaust several room air changes every hour.

When air is removed from your house, “make-up” air must be brought into your house. That air will be drawn in around doors, cracks around windows, etc.  and that air will be the outside air temperature. This causes your heater or air conditioner to “work” to make it conditioned air.